# python query from scd2 pandas dataframe - find between from_date and to_date

Tags: python

I have a dataframe like the below one:
I have dataframe with columns object,old_value,new_value,from_Date,to_date
will have multiple rows for each object.

how can I find all the new_values in given date range i.e. between 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-31
if 2020-01-01 is not in from_date then pick the old value,

I want to get those values in as a list in another column

[image]

desired result

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start_Date='2020-01-01'
end_date='2020-01-31'

mask = (df['from_date'] > start_Date) & (df['start_date'] <= end_date) | (df['to_date'] > start_Date) & (
            df['to_date'] <= end_date)
df = df.loc[mask]